# How to Output a file during a query/job

Tags: sql, sql-server, output, jobs

I have created a scheduled job to automatically update data. Nothing too complex just an insert into a temp table and then an update.

I was wondering what syntax/query would i need in order to OUTPUT the updated data into a file showing which rows have been updated, so if needs be information could be rolled back?

Ive looked into the OUTPUT syntax but I cant quite get my head around it and plus it doesnt output this into a file.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of ways, but I would use SSIS.   That's if you have to have a file.   Personally, I'd rather keep the updated rows in a table.

Comment: My problem is that not all environments the job will be on have SSIS, so ideally it would need to be embedded within the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) cannot be used to output rows to a file. It outputs to the current result context or to a table (regular, temporary or variable).

What you need will have to be done using the [`BCP` utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx). This utility ships with SQL Server. You can build your `BCP` command in a `VARCHAR` and execute it as follows in your job:

```
DECLARE @shell_cmd VARCHAR(8000);
-- build your BCP command exporting to file
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_cmdshell @shell_cmd;
```